# Error CSV: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, S3BotoStorageFile found

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error when trying to read the **row** and **column** count of a **CSV**:

**> coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, S3BotoStorageFile found**

```
import csv

class CSV:
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file = file

    def read_file(self):
        data = []
        file_read = read_file(self.file)
        return file_read

    def get_row_count(self):
        return len(self.read_file())

    def get_column_count(self):
        new_data = self.read_file()
        return len(new_data[0])

    def get_data(self, rows=1):
        data = self.read_file()
        return data[:rows]

def read_file(self):
    with open(self.file, 'r') as f:
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(f.read().splitlines())]
    return data
```

**How do I resolve?**

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: `.splitlines()` returns a list. csv.reader don't take lists I believe

Comment: there's no need to add anything `csv.reader(f)` is enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, after reading your code my first reaction was OMG! How many does he open that poor file?

Here's a new version of your class

```
class CSV:
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file = file
        with open(self.file, 'r') as f:
            self.data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]

    def get_row_count(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def get_column_count(self):
        return len(self.data[0])

    def get_data(self, rows=1):
        return self.data
```

I also fixed your `csv.reader()` handling. It accepts a file object, no need to `.read()` or `.read().splitlines()`, it can only lead to errors. Which may be the reason why it failed.

Ok, given from what you say, you're working on AWS, and your file is not a string path to a file, but already a file object. So you don't need the `open()` part as is. You may want to modify your code so it is as follows:

```
class CSV:
    def __init__(self, f=None):
        self.file = f
        if isinstance(self.file, str): # if the file is a string, it's a path that has to be opened
            with open(self.file, 'r') as f:
                self.data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]
        elif isinstance(self.file, File) or isinstance(self.file, file): # if that's a file object, no need to open
            self.data = [row for row in csv.reader(self.file)]
        else: # otherwise, I don't know what to do, so aaaaaaaargh!
            raise Exception("File object type unknown: %s %s" % (type(file), file,))

    def get_row_count(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def get_column_count(self):
        return len(self.data[0])

    def get_data(self, rows=1):
        return self.data
```

Reading the S3BotoStorage.py, the S3BotoStorage class inherits from django.core.files.base.File, which inherits from django.core.files.utils.FileProxyMixin, which is a composition of attributes of the global python `file` class.

So a `File` object is not an instance of `file`, but it has a compatible interface. Therefore, in the previous code I have tested whether the `self.file` is a `str`, then it shall be a path that we `open()` so we get a `file()` and parse it. Otherwise, `self.file` is a `File` object or a `file()` object, and we just need to parse it. If it's neither of those, then it's an error, and we shall except.

Comment: Thanks @zmo really helpful :) very cool. I still get the error coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found on this line now: with open(self.file, 'r') as f:

Comment: where does 'File' come from? is that an import from Python?

Comment: in your case, that `File` object is `from django.core.files.base import File` (cf [S3BotoStorage.py](https://bitbucket.org/madssj/django-storages/src/2930ca5815ca/S3BotoStorage.py)) Otherwise it comes from [django.core.files.utils.FileProxyMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/utils.py), which is a composition of the `file` object's attributes.

Comment: Amazing answer thanks so much for explaining this all so clearly.